# mat-table with input change value

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="data" *ngFor="let formGroup of getPartControls(); let i = index">
   <mat-table [dataSource]="data.orderPositions">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="relevance">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>price</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{ element.price }}</mat-cell>  ---> RESULT PRICE


        <button> EDIT </button>   -----> EDIT BUTTON
        <input matInput type="number">       ------> INPUT
      </ng-container>
   </mat-table>
  </div>
</form>
```

There is a table.
Initially, I receive data that falls into `data.orderPositions`. When loading, a table with prices `element.price` is displayed, when click on the EDIT button, an input appears through which can change the price in this cell.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to tap into the input values being changed. But you could exchange blur event for some other event.

html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let series">
        <input
            type="text"
            matInput
            autocomplete="off"
            [(ngModel)]="series.displayName"
            (blur)="change(series)"
        />
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'series-table',
  templateUrl: './series-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./series-table.component.scss']
})
export class SeriesTableComponent implements OnInit {

  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<SeriesDto>;

  ngOnInit(){    
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SeriesDto>(
         <DATA FROM SOMEWHERE>
      );
  }

  change(series: SeriesDto){
    if(series.displayName){
        // do something
    }
  }
}
```